# Getting an AttributeError, when adding .text attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have tried the script below and it works just fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

pr= input("search: ")

source= requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off'.format(pr)).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

url= soup.find_all('div', class_=('_3O0U0u'))
whole_product_list= []
whole_url_list= []
main_product_list= []
main_url_list= []
        

for i in url:
    tag_a_data= i.find_all('a')
    for l in tag_a_data:
        product_list= l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n')

        if product_list:
            main_product_list.append(product_list.text)

        else:
            product_ok= l.get('title')
            main_product_list.append(product_ok)

print(main_product_list)
```

so for example, if I pass "samsung" as input it returns a list for available attribute "div" with the given class Id, which is passed as arguments and if I pass something else as input like "shoes" which has "title" attribute it returns a list of all the titles available in it's html.

But if I reverse the order, like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

pr= input("search: ")

source= requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off'.format(pr)).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

url= soup.find_all('div', class_=('_3O0U0u'))
whole_product_list= []
whole_url_list= []
main_product_list= []
main_url_list= []
        


for i in url:
    tag_a_data= i.find_all('a')
    for l in tag_a_data:
        product_list = l.get('title')

        

        if product_list:
            main_product_list.append(product_list)

        else:
            product_ok= l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n').text
            main_product_list.append(product_ok)    


print(main_product_list)
```

it starts giving an attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tess.py", line 28, in <module>
    product_ok= l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I'm not getting why the first script is working fine based on if-else operation but second is not.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the source of the webpage won't always contain a div with that class? Do you expect the name `_3wU53n` to have some special meaning?

Comment: Absolutely no, it won't be the same always.

Comment: So then you can't reasonably expect to `.find` it always with a specific search target? Maybe you need to think of a better rule for identifying the div you want.

Comment: Before trying that out, I have checked a few other webpages for same content and it had the same class. so, i thought it'd be fine using that class for identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following data collected for your "l" values

- item1 `<title>title1</title><div class_= '_3wU53n'>xyz</div>`
- item2 `<title>title1</title><div>xyz</div>`
- item3 `<title>title1</title><div class_= '_3wU53n'>xyz</div>`

Using the first code, your `product_list` variable will contain item1 and item3. Then you can get the `title` of the given items as they are available. So the code works without any problem.

Using the second code, your `product_list` variable will contain item1, item2, and item3. But in this case, you won't get the required `div` tag, as it doesn't exist for the second item. This causes the attribute error.

The simple thing is items in the database will always have a title, but most likely won't have the required `div` tag always.

The following change should get it working:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

pr= input("search: ")

source= requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off'.format(pr)).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

url= soup.find_all('div', class_=('_3O0U0u'))
whole_product_list= []
whole_url_list= []
main_product_list= []
main_url_list= []
        


for i in url:
    tag_a_data= i.find_all('a')
    for l in tag_a_data:
        product_list = l.get('title')

        

        if product_list:
            main_product_list.append(product_list)

        else:
            if l.find("div", class_='_3wU53n'):
                product_ok= l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n').text
                main_product_list.append(product_ok)    


print(main_product_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
product_ok= l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n').text
```

`l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n')` returns `None`, meaning it doesn't find the div. `None` values haven't got a `text` property, so it raises an `AttributeError` exception.

A fix would be to use the new walrus operator:

```
if product_ok := l.find('div', class_= '_3wU53n'):
    product_ok = product_ok.text
```